# How to Update the values from datatable to datagridview using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable

I have a datatable (`dtAmount`) which has two columns `[HeadID]` and `[Amount]` and I also have a datagridview which has two columns `[HeadID]` , `[Amount]` and some other columns.

This datagridview has already been bound with a datasource and `HeadID` is filled with values but respective `Amount` is null. The `HeadID` in `dtAmount` has the respective values in `[Amount]` column and hence I want to update amount for respective head into datagridview using the values from `dtAmount`.

Comment: What do you currently have for your code?

Comment: Can't you just bind `dtAmount` (which has both values, as I understand) to your data grid view? Then both `Head` and `Amount` would be filled...... or am I misunderstanding something??

Comment: @marc_s - OP inidicated the DataGridView had other columns in addition to the HeadID and Amount; so I would expect binding to the new table would cause loss of data in the control (but I rarely do WinForms, so I could be wrong).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to modify the DataGridView's binding source to include the amount as well as the additional data filling the other columns?

Comment: @Tim: this would mean he probably has **two datatables** really - one he binds to the grid, and then this second `dtAmount` .....

Comment: @marc_s - I would agree, hence my most recent comment.   Seems it'd be easier to get the data in one grab up front; but it's hard to tell for sure without more details.

Comment: Yes. But datagridview is already bound with different datasource and has 6 different number of columns including headID and Amount. In the actual scenario the amount for each and every head is calculated in seperate SP and now i have to update those amount into the datagrid (already data bound).

Comment: @Prem: I would agree with Tim - try to add this `Amount` column to your original datatable that you already bind to the grid. You cannot bind a single grid to multiple datatables and pick and choose your columns...

Comment: @Prem - do you have control over the SP's?  In other words, can you modify things so that you can do this in one grab?  Or are there other constraints/requirements preventing that?

Comment: Are any of you guys going to answer rather than just comment?

Comment: @hugh jadick Not without more details!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you "Merge" function of the DataTable class as follows:

```
yourDataTable.Merge(dtAmount,true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
```

> //     Merge the specified System.Data.DataTable with the current
>   DataTable, indicating whether to preserve changes and how to handle missing schema in the current DataTable.